# Experimenting with SSLStrip+ on the same machine

Tags: tls, linux, iptables, hsts, sslstrip

I am trying to play around to understand how SSLStrip+ works by:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
$ sudo iptables --flush
$ sudo iptables --flush -t nat
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 9000
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-port 53
$ python sslstrip.py -l 9000 -a log.txt
```

Then, I prepend 127.0.0.1 as a DNS in `/etc/resolve.conf` and I configure `dns2proxy` and fire up:

```
$ echo ".fakeexample.com 192.168.1.123" >> domains.cfg
$ sudo python dns2proxy.py -i enp3s0 -u 192.168.1.123
```

192.168.1.123 is the target IP (also my own machine running all commands above).

Then, I fire up my browser to hit http://fakeexample.com (fakeexample.com isn't on the HSTS preload list according to hstspreload.org)

I thought sslstrip+ would pick up the traffic from the browser but according to sslstrip+'s log, it doesn't.  And the browser states connection refused.

What is missing?

Comment: Unless you are changing it, iirc it listens on 10000. Also, see https://serverfault.com/a/211544/235706

Comment: @multithr3at3d when I started `sslstrip`, I specified `-l 9000`, which will make sslstrip+ listens to port 9000 (according to the help page).  You mean the victim's browser (my own browser in my case) will go through loopback interface even it sees ip of 192.168.123 instead of 127.0.0.1?  I though loopback would be used if the ip is 127.0.0.1, no?

Comment: the network stack sees that the destination address belongs to the current host, so it never needs to hit the network card

Comment: @multithr3at3d got it.  I just tried `sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -o lo --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9000`.  sslstrip+'s log still shows nothing when my browser tries to access http://fakeexample.com.  Not sure what goes wrong.

Comment: I also checked to make sure my box has an interface called `lo`

Comment: Try removing `-o lo`? Or you could just set your browser's HTTP proxy settings to point to where SSLstrip is listening.